# How to use kubectl patch to add list entry without duplicate?

Tags: kubectl, minikube

I have the following Minikube default service account:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: gcr-secret
- name: awsecr-cred
- name: dpr-secret
- name: acr-secret
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-11-18T20:21:13Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "10953591"
  uid: edcc687f-dbb5-472d-8847-b4dc29096b48
```

I can add a new `imagePullSecrets` entry using the following `kubectl patch` command:

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default --type=json -p '[{"op": "add", "path": "/imagePullSecrets/-", "value": {name: artifactory-credentials}}]'
```

Here's the update default service account:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: gcr-secret
- name: awsecr-cred
- name: dpr-secret
- name: acr-secret
- name: artifactory-credentials
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-11-18T20:21:13Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "10956724"
  uid: edcc687f-dbb5-472d-8847-b4dc29096b48
```

However, when I run the `kubectl patch` command a second time, a duplicate `imagePullSecrets` entry is added:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: gcr-secret
- name: awsecr-cred
- name: dpr-secret
- name: acr-secret
- name: artifactory-credentials
- name: artifactory-credentials
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-11-18T20:21:13Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "10957065"
  uid: edcc687f-dbb5-472d-8847-b4dc29096b48
```

How can I use `kubectl patch` to add a `imagePullSecrets` entry only when the entry doesn't already exist?  I don't want duplicate `imagePullSecrets` entries.

I'm using Minikube v1.28.0 and kubectl client version v1.26.1 / server version v1.25.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Unfortunately in the official documentation there is no mention of how to add validation for the kubecl patch command. Although you can try with this 

    **kubectl patch serviceaccount default --type=json -p '{"imagePullSecrets":[{"name": "gcr-secret"},{"name": "artifactory-credentials"},{"name": "acr-secret"}]}'**
But every time we need to add an entire list of secrets.

Comment: Thanks Dharani.  That's in line with what I've found as well.  Since I was looking to add the **imagePullSecrets** entry in a Python script, what I did was first query the service account via `kubectl get serviceaccount default -o json` and then only perform the `kubectl patch` command if the **imagePullSecrets** entry wasn't already in the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK unfortunately there is no such filter available the [official documentation](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/). But We can do a workaround by using the general syntax like `kubectl patch serviceaccount default --type=json -p '{"imagePullSecrets":[{"name": "gcr-secret"},{"name": "artifactory-credentials"},{"name": "acr-secret"}]}'.` But we have to update all the  `imagePullSecrets` everytime.

As **@Geoff Alexander** mentioned the other way is to get the details of resource and validate if the required property is available in the resource, as mentioned in the above comment like `$kubectl get serviceaccount -o json` or `$kubectl get serviceaccount -o yaml`.